# The value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n^6}$ using the Fourier Transformation

Tags: fourier-series, fast-fourier-transform

How to compute the sum given in $(1)$, from the fourier transformation of 
$\pi x |x|-x^3$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$. 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n^6} \tag{1}
$$

Suppose we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well... you know what to do, find Fourier series.

Comment: If we know the value for $\zeta(6)$, then the needed alternating series has the value $\zeta(6)-2\cdot\frac 1{2^6}\zeta(6)$.

Comment: The Fourier series of your function gives $\zeta(6)$ for its $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ norm, so you need to use $\eta(6) = (1-2^{1-6}) \zeta(6)$ anyway

Comment: @dan_fulea they said they know the value of $\zeta(6)$.

Comment: If we have the value of $\zeta(6)$ then of course $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^6}=\ \left(\frac 1{1^6}+\frac 1{2^6}+\frac 1{3^6}+\frac 1{4^6}+\dots\right)-2\cdot\frac 1{2^6}\left(\frac 1{1^6}+\frac 1{2^6}+\dots\right)\ .$$ Job is done. (If we really need as a condition to go through the Fourier Transform, then we go through the Fourier Transform of the zero function.)